# How to build asynchronous data loading with simple configuration

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool

I have a process in my web app, it's just a sequence of CRUD requests. An order is usually strict, the only difference is an Id will be different for every process. I'd like to make "asynchronous" data loading. For example:

1. A user makes a request for Step 1.
2. A Server gives to him/her response and as soon as the server builds complete response it starts to build data for Step 2, 3, 5... and put it in a cache.

My question is: could you advise any mechanism which will make it simple and readable? That's' the main requirement. Does Spring have something for this? (WebFlux not well fits the architecture)

Comment: if you are using SpringBoot architecture you can use the annotation @Async. Which makes it quite simple

Comment: Since you mentioned, order is necessary, that means the the process which is picked first should complete first, then any other process may be picked up by the processor, for this you may set the count of thread(in threadpoolexecutor) to 1 while using spring async functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `producer-consumer design pattern`

For example.
1. Get a request from a client, do step 1 work.
2. Response client.
3. Make a `task entity`, then add it to a `task queue`.
4. Http worker thread end.
5. Work Step 2-N in another thread. And put results in the cache.

For frameworks, [akka](https://github.com/akka/akka) is a good choice.
`RxJava` may be also good.

And you can implement it by yourself.